# Array to string conversion error when making soap request

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I'm doing a simple request like this

```
        $wsdl = "http://.../wsdl/FileArchive";
        $client = new SoapClient($wsdl);


        $parameters= array(
                        "FileName" => "file.jpg"
                       );

        $values = $client->GetFileInfo($parameters);
```

I'm getting "Array to string conversion" where the GetFileInfo method is being called.

The method is defined in wsdl like this :

```
<message name="GetFileInfo0Request">
<part name="FileName" type="xs:string"/>
</message>
```

I've searched for it, and found out it could occur when there is some complex type, but here is just a string. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rather than this `$values = $client->GetFileInfo($parameters);`

Try this instead: `$values = $client->__soapCall('GetFileInfo', $parameters);`

Comment: Thank you for response, now it doesn't show that error, but "Could not connect to host"...but it should be available.

Comment: Does the host require some sort of authentication scheme, like a username and password?

Comment: I had the same problem. Does anyone know the reason? Why does it work with __soapCall?

Comment: I changed this code: 

$response = call_user_func_array( array( $this->client, $action ), array( $request ) );


Into this code:

$response = $this->client->__soapCall( $action, array( $request ) );

But it did not help, I still get the Notice. $request contains an object!

Answer (score -2):

You must send a simple array.

```
 $parameters= array("file.jpg");
```